# Qual comando SQL utilizar para alterar um carácter da placa dos veículos - Padrão Mercosul

Tags: oracle11g

Utilizo um sistema que trabalha com o banco de dados Oracle 11g e tenho a tabela (Tab_PlaVei) com o campo string (PlaVei), formato **UUU9999**. Preciso ajustar este campo para o novo padrão de placas do Mercosul, formato **UUU9U99**.

Qual comando `SQL` devo utilizar para corrigir todas as placas que já foram cadastradas no formato **UUU9999** alterando para o novo formato **UUU9U99**, ou seja, alterar o 2º caractere numérico ou o 5º da string da placa, conforme a tabela padrão de placa Mercosul:
string 0 -> A; 1 -> B; 2 -> C; 3 -> D; 4 -> E; 5 -> F; 6 -> G; 7 -> H; 8 -> I e 9 -> J.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: não seria o `update`?

Comment: sim, mas se possível o código completo

Comment: ah quer um código completo? desculpe mas acho que esse não é o propósito do SO.. .aqui ajudamos a resolver um problema, não resolver completamente... de uma olhada no comando `update`, tente até onde conseguir resolver, poste seu código aqui explicando o que fez e qual o problema que podemos lhe ajudar melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Oque você está querendo fazer é um pouquinho mais complicado do que parece. Vamos lá: para você atualizar a tabela, utilizar o comando `UPDATE`; para fazer o que deseja e modificar um determinado caractere na string, o comando `STUFF()` deve funcionar perfeitamente; já para substituir o inteiro pela letra do alfabeto correspondente, tente o comando `SUBSTRING()`.

## Exemplo da função STUFF:

```sql
STUFF(ABC, @n, 1, 'X')
```

Pega o valor do campo ABC, começa na posição `@n`, deleta `1` carácter e insere o carácter `'X'` na posição.

## Exemplo da função SUBSTRING:

```sql
SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ABC, 1)
```

Substitui o inteiro 1 por A, 2 por B, 3 por C e assim por diante.

## Código final:

```sql
UPDATE tableName
SET PlaVei = CONCAT( -- Concatena tudo para formar a nova placa
    SUBSTRING(PlaVei, 1, 4), -- Caracteres antes da letra alterada
    SUBSTRING("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNIOPQRSTUVWXYZ", SUBSTRING(PlaVei, 5, 1), 1), -- Altera o inteiro pela letra
    SUBSTRING(PlaVei, 6, 7) -- Caracteres depois da letra alterada
)
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Lucas, pelo que entendi o código está conforme a necessidade, porém ao executar no oracle recebo o erro ORA-00909, consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Eu consegui alterar a máscara deste campo de UUU9999 para UUU9U99